# Conditional Conditons in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a combobox with 3 values: `All`, `Failed`, `Completed`.

`ALL`: load All rows and no condition.
`Failed` and `Completed`: load with a condition on column 'status'.

ALL:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Location
```

Failed and Completed:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Location Where status = 'Failed'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Location Where status = 'Completed'
```

I have just two statues 'Failed' and 'Completed'. 'All' is a combo-box value that load all rows without condition

I want to do this all in one query. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @status varchar(15)

--set the status

SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Location
WHERE Status = @status OR @status = 'ALL'
```

Comment: I have just two statues 'FAILED' and 'Compeleted'. All load all rows without condition

Comment: @ArMaN - Have you tried this query? If there is only two status then how will you know about all status?

Comment: If you set your @status to be 'ALL', then all rows will be returned.

Comment: tnx :) help me here plz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780119/null-conditons-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Make your combo-box to send a parameter call @status. Send @status = null when you need to load all row.

```
Select *
from tbl_location
where @status is null or status = @status;
```

Comment: I have just two statues 'FAILED' and 'Compeleted'. All load all rows without condition