# NULL Conditons in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this:

```
ID      | Code    | YEAR
--------+---------+----------
0       | 1       | '1998'
1       | 5       |  NULL
2       | 7       | '2013'
3       | 1       | '1892'
4       | 5       |  NULL
5       | 7       | '1900'
```

I have a combobox with 3 values: `All`, `NULLs`, `Not Nulls`.

`ALL`: load All rows and no condition.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Location
```

`Nulls`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Location Where YEAR is Null
```

'Not Nulls'

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Location Where YEAR is not Null
```

'All' is a combo-box value that load all rows without condition

I want to do this all in one query. What can I do?

Comment: what do you mean all in one query?

Comment: @marc_s no it's diffrent, this is about null values

Comment: @ObieMD5 i don't want to use if conditions

Comment: I do not think you are going to get around using an if statement or a switch.  I only say this because you have a query that request everything, and then you have a query with a filter on it.  If they all had filters it could be done without an if statement.

Comment: @ArMaN - I am asking you again: How do you decide that you want all rows?

Comment: @marc_s marc this is not duplicated! questions are diffrent

Comment: @hims056 i want show all rows in gridview

Comment: @ArMaN - Check my answer. I understand that you can't set `YEAR = @Status` since it is condition for `Null` and `Not Null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the value of the Combobox in `@Status`:

Here you need to set conditions like this:

```
DECLARE @Status varchar(15)
--set the Status

SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Location
WHERE (@Status = 'All' 
       OR (@Status = 'Nulls' AND YEAR IS NULL) 
       OR (@Status = 'Not Nulls' AND YEAR IS NOT NULL)
      )
```

Comment: Downvoter any problem? And FYI: I didn't ask for upvote. OP did.

Comment: ArMan deleted his comment.  He was asking for you to upvote his question after you answered it.  I wrote my comment and then he deleted his comment.  Also just so you know I did not downvote the question.  Was saying that because so many others have.

Comment: @ObieMD5 - I am not saying you downvoted me. :) But someone else may have downvoted by misinterpreting that you were saying me so please use [`@Username`](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to reply someone. Now just move on. :)